# How to feed table column in search filter

Tags: php

```html
<form action="retrieve1.php" method="post">
<select name="Users">
<option value="" selected="selected">Grade</option>
<option value=""></option>

</select>
<select name="Jobs">
<option value="" selected="selected">School</option>


<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>


</select>
<select name="Team">
<option value="" selected="selected">Team</option>
<option value="kipp warriors">kipp warriors</option>
<option value="mary winners">mary winners</option>


</select>
<select name="Students">
<option value="" selected="selected">Students</option>
<option value="kipp warriors">kayla smith</option>
<option value="mary winners">john doe</option>



</select>
<input type="submit" value="Find" />
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

I have created above HTML form, how do i automatically feed table field in each filter ? For instance in Team filter- i wish to automatically feed Team information from mysql database. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try it for your self. Just search for "mysqli php" and try it yourself. If you have a real problem make a question.

Comment: @Alexander appreciate the direction

Comment: no problem. glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SQL queries to retrieve the desired info from the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Use `mysqli_query` and store the rows in an associative array which you can call using `$rows['grade']`, for example.

Comment: Thanks i will head into this direction